# perl threads: is exit needed?

Tags: multithreading, perl

```
    # Check thread's state
    if ($thr->is_running()) {
        sleep(1);
    }
    if ($thr->is_joinable()) {
        $thr->join();
    }

    # Send a signal to a thread
    $thr->kill('SIGUSR1');

    # Exit a thread
    threads->exit();
```

I'm unclear on the documentation on [perldoc threads](https://metacpan.org/pod/threads).

Is `threads->exit()` needed if a thread is already joined or detached?

If it's not needed, and given the fact that we always have to either `join` or `detach`, when do we want to call `threads->exit()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like how `exit` allows you to exit the current process before reaching its end, `threads->exit()` allows you to exit the current thread before reaching its end. You don't need to use them if there's nothing to execute after them.

Comment: oh so if i call threads->exit(), then i wont have to call join() and vice versa. Is this correct?

Comment: huh? `exit` is used to exit the current thread. `join` is used to wait for a thread to complete. They are unrelated!

Comment: ohhh so threads->exit() is only called from inside the thread and join is called from the main code that invoked the thread.